# wso2 screen lock and policy enforcement

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

in wso2 emm, when in policy i set a passcode policy, and set the policy to enforce. 
There is no enforcement for screen lock, is that nominal or a bug ? 
how can i enforce the device to have a screen lock password or pin code protected ?

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the normal behavior. You don't want a policy to lock the screen. Locking the screen is a simple operation as you quickly press the power button of your device.
You can send the passcode policy and it will be apply to your device on the fly. But you can see the password screen once you unlock the screen.

Comment: hi, what i mean, is when i set a passcode policy, it don't force the device to have a screen lock. i mean, if the device is set with no pin code, or just a swipe it will stay that way, and i do want that all device have screen lock forced so people can't just press the power button and have the splashscreen ? basically my device is always unlocked, despite the passcode policy. is that a bug, or is there a possibility to force the device to be set with the lock ?

Comment: You can set 'Change Screen Lock Passcode' policy for your purpose.

Comment: yes, and then, the user enter the passcode, go to parameters, deactivate the lock screen. The device show up as violating policy, and, it seems there is no enforcement to reset the passcode beyond the first time. policy set to enforcement don't enforce policy when those are violated after the first application is that normal or a bug ? it seems like a bug to me, i don't see the point in having the violation reported, but no enforcement beyond that, even if the policy is set to enforce ... and more, violated policy don't show warning on end user device when set to enforce ..is that normal too ?

Comment: Yes, enforcement only happen only one time. You can create 'Acknowledge' or 'Warning' polices to notify admin or device user about the violation. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Managing+Policies

Comment: so all the "follow-up actions" as mentionned here, " WSO2 EMM will automatically generate a notification and carry out follow-up actions in the event a device is in violation of the enforced policy. The administrator can select the follow-up actions (e.g., send the user a warning message, enforce the policy again, and more) based on their security requirements. " is the choiche of warning, acknoledge, or enforce, but only happen once ? Is there a mean to force the script "policy enforcement" to run each time a violation is detected ?